# Google Docs Add-On Print Form Trigger

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, add-on

I would like to know if it is possible create and add-on to Google Docs that will allow me to track whether a document has been printed in Google Docs, so that I can do some post processing, in my app.

Comment: Questions asking "Can I do X? / Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, it's usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I do not know whether the above is possible or not and was hoping that a Google expert would, in the first instance, provide me with some useful information.